# Dynamically apply network analysis to list of text files in r

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, text-files

I have a folder "Disintegration T1" containing around 50 text files which look like this, where each text file name corresponds to a team:

```
> 1
0  0  0  0  1
1  0  0  0  1
0  1  0  0  1
0  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  0
> 2
0  1  1  0  1
0  0  1  1  1
1  1  0  1  1
1  1  1  0  1
0  0  0  0  0
> 3
0  1  1  1  
1  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  
1  0  0  0
```

I am attempting to automate the process of running network analysis on all of the text files, which includes the following functions:

```
library(sna)
centralization(x,betweenness)
centralization(x,degree)
centralization(x,evcent)
gden(x)
```

One of the problems I am having with this is that these analyses must be performed on matrices, and R defaults to reading these files as data-frames.  I am also having trouble constructing the code in general.  My goal is to automate the process so that the results are added to a data-frame where each row corresponds to each text file, and each column corresponds to the performed analysis, so that the final results looks like:

```
> results
   gden   betweenness   degree   evcent
1   #          #           #        #
2   #          #           #        #
3   #          #           #        #
```

(Number refers to the corresponding analysis result)  I have tried the following which is not working:

```
networkanalysis<-function(x){
gden<-gden(x)
centb<-centralization(x,betweenness)
centd<-centralization(x,degree)
cente<-centralization(x,evcent)
return(gden)
return(centb)
return(centd)
return(cente)
}
out<-do.call("rbind",lapply(dir(),function(x)networkanalysis(data=as.matrix(read.table(x)))))
```

Where my working directory is set to the folder with the text files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only `return` one result from a function, so wrap those values in a `data.frame` and return the data.frame.

```
networkanalysis <- function(x) {
    data.frame(
        gden=gden(x),
        centb=centralization(x,betweenness),
        centd=centralization(x,degree),
        cente=centralization(x,evcent)
    )
}
```

Then, call your function on each file and `rbind` the results together with `do.call`.

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dir(), function(x) networkanalysis(as.matrix(read.table(x)))))
```

#### Edit

To add filenames as rownames,

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(dir(), function(x)
    `rownames<-`(networkanalysis(as.matrix(read.table(x))), basename(x))))
```

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly.  One last thing which I should have posed in the initial question, but how could I go about making the row names correspond to text file names?  Thank you!

Comment: @costebk08 you can use `rownames(...) <-` or the fancy one-liner form, `\`rownames<-\`(...)`.  So, you could replace the function in the `do.call` with `function(x) \`rownames<-\`(networkanalysis(as.matrix(read.table(x))), basename(x))))`